# how to parse xml through DOM in php

Tags: php, xmldom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<info>
   <report id="1">
      <book>
          <title>A</title>
      </book>
      <author>
          <name>xyz</name>
      </author>
   </report>
   <report id="2">
       <book>
           <title>B</title>
       </book>
       <author>
           <name>xyz</name>
       </author>
   </report>
   <report id="3">
       <book>
           <title>C</title>
       </book>
       <author>
           <name>xyz</name>
       </author>
  </report>
</info>
```

this is my xml and i want to retrieve each report and save it to database
I have load the xml file to dom and can retrive value by using **nodeValue**.By using nodeValue i am getting values like A and XYZ but I want the value is in xml formatted

     `<book>
          <title>A</title>
      </book>
      <author>
          <name>xyz</name>
      </author>`

Comment: @madan I do not understand your question, you want to read the xml file with PHP and then save the data to a database?

Comment: not data exactly want to access the each report block and save to database in xml format only

Comment: Ok but I need to know if you want to access each report block of xml file through PHP?

Comment: ya i am able to traverse by using the following line but can't getting entire block
`
    $document = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $document->loadXML(path)
    $reportNodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName('report');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to get each report node as well as its contents. You may do the following:

```
<?php
    $doc = DOMDocument::loadXML(' x m l  s t r i n g ');

    $reportNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('report');
    foreach($reportNodeList as $reportNode) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($doc->saveXML($reportNode));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use simpleXMl or simpleXMIterator to parse, each node would be a simpleXML element that you could independently output as XML.